# how 2 audio inputs are joined?

Tags: multiple

I have almost no prior idea of sound technology.
I want to combine some different sound inputs from different musical instruments but play it on the same loudspeaker or record it on a same computer. how to join the 2 or more Audio inputs electronically? like if all the instruments use a TRS jack, would I connect all the tips together, all the rings together and all the sleeves together? or it needs some special kind of circuit? What would be the circuit diagram to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to connect the inputs electronically - it will not work, as your sources will all have different impedances.

You would always use a mixer. They range from very cheap to very expensive, but they are ubiquitous. Buy one in your price range with the required number of inputs. It could be a mixer as part of an audio interface for a computer, or a stand alone mixer.